# Examine MultiIndexSearcher Example Umbraco

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, examine

Trying to get a searcher in razor using the MultiIndexSearcher provider.

```
<add name="MultiIndexSearcher"
    type="Examine.LuceneEngine.Providers.MultiIndexSearcher, Examine"
    indexSets="ExternalIndexSet,CustomIndexSet" enableLeadingWildcards="true"
    />
```

This results in zero results  - both via code and in Examine Management in back office.

Does anyone have an example or code snippet for using the MultiIndexSearcher as I am clearly missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to specify analyzer, something like this:

```
<add name="MultiIndexSearcher"
type="Examine.LuceneEngine.Providers.MultiIndexSearcher, Examine"
indexSets="ExternalIndexSet,CustomIndexSet" enableLeadingWildcards="true"
analyzer="Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer, Lucene.Net"
/>
```